# MariaDB 10.2.35 Memory Spikes

Tags: mysql, php, database, mariadb

On an AWS EC2 T3.large instance I'm hosting a website built with the Cake PHP framework. It utilises the MariaDB version 10.2.35. I'm having an issue whereby the memory for the server is spiking.

When MariaDB starts, it uses a small portion of memory - perhaps a few hundred MB of the total available (~ 8GB). However, I can't seem to find any specific web request that is causing the database memory to spike. Then out of seemingly nothing, the memory usage will spike by a couple of GB until the kernel eventually comes along and kills the MariaDB. This is a little infuriating as there doesn't seem to be an obvious cause for this memory usage. Perhaps someone could assist me in diagnosing this further and looking for what the cause may be.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the default configuration of MariaDB?

Comment: I've inherited this server - but not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Let's see the my.cnf file

Answer (score 2):

Same here on a VPS with Debian 9 and a php web site.

I noted this "new" behavior after upgrade from 10.2.34 (working perfectly) to 10.2.35 (process killed after eating all of available memory, restarted, killed again and so on...).
It seems this is not really related to hosting server (or hosting provider) as your host configuration is different from mine.
No modification were done on the MariaDB configuration. What I've done was "apt update/apt upgrade". That's all.

At the moment, I had to downgrade to 10.2.34 as a workaround.

The configured deb repo is :

```
deb http://mariadb.mirrors.ovh.net/MariaDB/repo/10.2/debian stretch main
```

So, packages are those provided directly by MariaDB.
There is the list of packages updated during the upgrade from 10.2.34 to 10.2.35 :

```
galera-3/unknown 25.3.31-stretch amd64 [upgradable from: 25.3.30-stretch]
libmariadb3/unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch amd64 [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
mariadb-client-10.2/unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch amd64 [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
mariadb-client-core-10.2/unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch amd64 [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
mariadb-common/unknown,unknown,unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch all [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
mariadb-server/unknown,unknown,unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch all [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
mariadb-server-10.2/unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch amd64 [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
mariadb-server-core-10.2/unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch amd64 [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
mysql-common/unknown,unknown,unknown 10.2.35+maria~stretch all [upgradable from: 10.2.34+maria~stretch]
```

It seems to be related to https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24117

And MariaDB published two days ago a new corrected version : 10.2.36

Comment: Thank you - that's interesting to hear that you've had a similar issue. I'll roll back and report back..

Comment: How did you go about downgrading as it seems it's unsupported by MariaDB. Was it a dump of the tables, remove 10.2.35, install 10.2.34 and re-import tables?

Comment: You don't have to remove before 'apt install' the previous version. I dumped and restored the database I think, not sure about it. As it is a very minor change in MariaDB I'm not sure that you cannot just downgrade software without touching databases. However, some tables were broken (before the downgrade) because of the several kills/restarts and I had to repair them with mysqlrepair to be sure that tables are healthy. In my case there were only myisam tables.

Comment: I updated my answer above. A new version 10.2.36 is now published by MariaDB.